# Storing API credentials files on GitHub

Tags: python, angular, oauth-2.0, gmail

I'm working on a Python Angular app that integrates Gmail API. I have 3 JSON files for token, credentials, and a specific file which I need to authenticate the Gmail API so my app can generate emails to send to email addresses via OAuth2. I got my app to work using the credentials. I've been wondering about this question.

Is there a way to store those files without committing them to GitHub? I want to host this app on the Heroku platform but I don't want to compromise that by including those JSON files which contain the secret client key, ids, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables. Here's a Heroku guide:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

How to use them locally, depends on your OS and/or shell you're using. It can be a `.bashrc` file (or `.zshrc` or another one like that) in your home directory, it could be something clickable in Windows.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution, but I do have a problem. 1 file needs to be referenced by an environment variable (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) set by my machine. I haven't written any code that referenced this environment variable. That particular file has some sensitive info like project-id, private_key,etc. It seems like it needs to stay in the JSON file for it to work.

Comment: @blazerchamp if it's not too large, you can maybe JSON.stringify it and still store it in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

If those values do not change, you can use Heroku config vars, otherwise I suggest trying MongoDB. Here's some guides I found:

- Integrating MongoDB cloud with Python app: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-python-and-mongodb
- Getting started with heroku config vars: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars